# Sphinx search: charset table difficulties

Tags: php, utf-8, sphinx, character

I am loosing my mind on this for two days now...

I would like to use slovenian letters in sphinx search, all english ones + č ž š (and just in case ć)

I was looking all over the net to get the proper chars but I found squat...

so I decided to make my own step by step...

this is my index

```
index classifieds
{
    source          = classifieds_src
    path            = c:\Sphinx\data\classifieds
    docinfo         = extern

    min_infix_len       = 2
    infix_fields        = title,keywords,summary,text
    expand_keywords     = 1
    enable_star     = 1


    charset_type        = utf-8
    charset_table = 0..9, a..z, _, A..Z->a..z,-, U+002C, \
    U+010C->U+010D, U+0106->U+0107, U+0160->U+0161, U+017D->U+017E, \
    U+010D->c,U+0107->c, U+0161->s, U+017E->z, \
    U+010D, U+0107, U+0161, U+017E
}
```

where I mapped big Č, Ć Š Ž to their lowercase counterparts, and added mapping from
č into c, ć into c, š into s and ž into z
and finally I added those four chars to the table....

these are my classifieds titles:

t1: HP USB optična miška za prenosnik RH304
t2: Čiška PCplus MO-U033+F2 (optična, brezžična, PS/2)
t3: Miška Logitech optična Nano M235 siva

db encoding: utf8_general_ci
table's encoding: utf8_general_ci
title field encoding: utf8_general_ci

test case:

```
$testcase = array(
        "miška",
        "mi*ka",
        "Čiška",
        "čiška",
        "miska",
        "usb prenosnik",
        "prenosnik miska",
        "miška usb"
);

//api settings:

$this->sphinx->SetArrayResult(true);
$this->sphinx->setLimits(0, 100);
$this->sphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE, '@weight DESC');
$this->sphinx->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25);
$this->sphinx->SetFieldWeights(array("title"=>100, "keywords"=>80, "summary"=>60,
"text"=>20, "slug"=>10));
```

and finally the test results:

Keyword (total / total_found)
words

```
miška     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*miška*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [miška] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

mi*ka     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*mi*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 3
            [hits] => 4
        )

    [mi] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [*2aka*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [2aka] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

Čiška     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*čiška*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [čiška] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

čiška     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*čiška*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [čiška] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

miska     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*miska*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [miska] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

usb prenosnik     (1/1)

Array
(
    [*usb*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [usb] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [*prenosnik*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [prenosnik] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

)

prenosnik miska     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*prenosnik*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [prenosnik] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [*miska*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [miska] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

)

miška usb     (0/0)

Array
(
    [*miška*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [miška] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 0
            [hits] => 0
        )

    [*usb*] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

    [usb] => Array
        (
            [docs] => 1
            [hits] => 1
        )

)
```

You can clearly see I get positive results only in the queries without slovenian special chars

Please, please help I am loosing my mind on this

Comment: OMG! I did it!

[Found the answer here][1]


  [1]: http://ryaneby.com/2009/11/21/unicode-and-sphinx.html

I needed to add

sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8

to my source definition... obviously the DB did not connect trough utf8 by default!

WOOO HOOOO

Comment: I would, but it won't let me :S 100 reputation needed...
please post it yourself, I;ll confirm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that sphinx indexer wasn't using utf8 character set by default. Fixed by adding the following to sphinx.conf

```
sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
```

References

- http://ryaneby.com/2009/11/21/unicode-and-sphinx.html
- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-sql-query-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you could find many different charset tables, maybe one of the would be suitable for your language: http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters you should setup. They are ngram_len and ngram_chars.

First, I got the same problem with you. Then I read the book *Introduction to search with sphinx* , I found the default charset and ngram_chars is for english and russian only. So you have to add those by yourself.

In my case, I made these changs, for Chinese:

```
charset_table = U+FF10..U+FF19->0..9, 0..9, U+FF41..U+FF5A->a..z, U+FF21..U+FF3A->a..z,\
    A..Z->a..z, a..z, U+0149, U+017F, U+0138, U+00DF, U+00FF, U+00C0..U+00D6->U+00E0..U+00F6,\
    U+00E0..U+00F6, U+00D8..U+00DE->U+00F8..U+00FE, U+00F8..U+00FE, U+0100->U+0101, U+0101,\
    U+0102->U+0103, U+0103, U+0104->U+0105, U+0105, U+0106->U+0107, U+0107, U+0108->U+0109,\
    U+0109, U+010A->U+010B, U+010B, U+010C->U+010D, U+010D, U+010E->U+010F, U+010F,\
    U+0110->U+0111, U+0111, U+0112->U+0113, U+0113, U+0114->U+0115, U+0115, U+0116->U+0117,\
    U+0117, U+0118->U+0119, U+0119, U+011A->U+011B, U+011B, U+011C->U+011D, U+011D,\
    U+011E->U+011F, U+011F, U+0130->U+0131, U+0131, U+0132->U+0133, U+0133, U+0134->U+0135,\
    U+0135, U+0136->U+0137, U+0137, U+0139->U+013A, U+013A, U+013B->U+013C, U+013C,\
    U+013D->U+013E, U+013E, U+013F->U+0140, U+0140, U+0141->U+0142, U+0142, U+0143->U+0144,\
    U+0144, U+0145->U+0146, U+0146, U+0147->U+0148, U+0148, U+014A->U+014B, U+014B,\
    U+014C->U+014D, U+014D, U+014E->U+014F, U+014F, U+0150->U+0151, U+0151, U+0152->U+0153,\
    U+0153, U+0154->U+0155, U+0155, U+0156->U+0157, U+0157, U+0158->U+0159, U+0159,\
    U+015A->U+015B, U+015B, U+015C->U+015D, U+015D, U+015E->U+015F, U+015F, U+0160->U+0161,\
    U+0161, U+0162->U+0163, U+0163, U+0164->U+0165, U+0165, U+0166->U+0167, U+0167,\
    U+0168->U+0169, U+0169, U+016A->U+016B, U+016B, U+016C->U+016D, U+016D, U+016E->U+016F,\
    U+016F, U+0170->U+0171, U+0171, U+0172->U+0173, U+0173, U+0174->U+0175, U+0175,\
    U+0176->U+0177, U+0177, U+0178->U+00FF, U+00FF, U+0179->U+017A, U+017A, U+017B->U+017C,\
    U+017C, U+017D->U+017E, U+017E, U+0410..U+042F->U+0430..U+044F, U+0430..U+044F,\
    U+05D0..U+05EA, U+0531..U+0556->U+0561..U+0586, U+0561..U+0587, U+0621..U+063A, U+01B9,\
    U+01BF, U+0640..U+064A, U+0660..U+0669, U+066E, U+066F, U+0671..U+06D3, U+06F0..U+06FF,\
    U+0904..U+0939, U+0958..U+095F, U+0960..U+0963, U+0966..U+096F, U+097B..U+097F,\
    U+0985..U+09B9, U+09CE, U+09DC..U+09E3, U+09E6..U+09EF, U+0A05..U+0A39, U+0A59..U+0A5E,\
    U+0A66..U+0A6F, U+0A85..U+0AB9, U+0AE0..U+0AE3, U+0AE6..U+0AEF, U+0B05..U+0B39,\
    U+0B5C..U+0B61, U+0B66..U+0B6F, U+0B71, U+0B85..U+0BB9, U+0BE6..U+0BF2, U+0C05..U+0C39,\
    U+0C66..U+0C6F, U+0C85..U+0CB9, U+0CDE..U+0CE3, U+0CE6..U+0CEF, U+0D05..U+0D39, U+0D60,\
    U+0D61, U+0D66..U+0D6F, U+0D85..U+0DC6, U+1900..U+1938, U+1946..U+194F, U+A800..U+A805,\
    U+A807..U+A822, U+0386->U+03B1, U+03AC->U+03B1, U+0388->U+03B5, U+03AD->U+03B5,\
    U+0389->U+03B7, U+03AE->U+03B7, U+038A->U+03B9, U+0390->U+03B9, U+03AA->U+03B9,\
    U+03AF->U+03B9, U+03CA->U+03B9, U+038C->U+03BF, U+03CC->U+03BF, U+038E->U+03C5,\
    U+03AB->U+03C5, U+03B0->U+03C5, U+03CB->U+03C5, U+03CD->U+03C5, U+038F->U+03C9,\
    U+03CE->U+03C9, U+03C2->U+03C3, U+0391..U+03A1->U+03B1..U+03C1,\
    U+03A3..U+03A9->U+03C3..U+03C9, U+03B1..U+03C1, U+03C3..U+03C9, U+0E01..U+0E2E,\
    U+0E30..U+0E3A, U+0E40..U+0E45, U+0E47, U+0E50..U+0E59, U+A000..U+A48F, U+4E00..U+9FBF,\
    U+3400..U+4DBF, U+20000..U+2A6DF, U+F900..U+FAFF, U+2F800..U+2FA1F, U+2E80..U+2EFF,\
    U+2F00..U+2FDF, U+3100..U+312F, U+31A0..U+31BF, U+3040..U+309F, U+30A0..U+30FF,\
    U+31F0..U+31FF, U+AC00..U+D7AF, U+1100..U+11FF, U+3130..U+318F, U+A000..U+A48F,\
    U+A490..U+A4CF
ngram_len       = 1


# n-gram characters list, for CJK indexing
# optional, default is empty
#
# ngram_chars       = U+3000..U+2FA1F

ngram_chars = U+4E00..U+9FBF, U+3400..U+4DBF, U+20000..U+2A6DF, U+F900..U+FAFF,\
    U+2F800..U+2FA1F, U+2E80..U+2EFF, U+2F00..U+2FDF, U+3100..U+312F, U+31A0..U+31BF,\
    U+3040..U+309F, U+30A0..U+30FF, U+31F0..U+31FF, U+AC00..U+D7AF, U+1100..U+11FF,\
    U+3130..U+318F, U+A000..U+A48F, U+A490..U+A4CF
```