# Sphinx/MySQL UTF8 & &trade; symbol

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

We use Sphinx for a site search, but I'm very new to it.

It doesn't like the ™ symbol (™) - in the results I just get the question-mark-in-a-diamond symbol.

I have set the following, but no difference.

```
    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre   = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `SET NAMES` includes the other SET.

Comment: These lines came from an accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637751/sphinx-search-charset-table-difficulties

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Sphinx
But try use utf8mb4_unicode_ci for the table encoding..

```
INSERT INTO testT (`fieldA`) VALUES ("™");
SELECT * FROM testT;
```

Seems to show a fine results

Comment: Thanks Itay - but I know the MySQL table is ok. When I read the data without Sphinx, I see the correct symbol.

Comment: Well, do `SELECT HEX(fieldA) FROM testT`.  It needs to show `E284A2`, not `&trade;` or anything else.